# Why won't my test work in Parse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

Im trying to run the test object in Parse to set up the use of Parse in my app. However i can't get it to work - very frustrating!!

I have checked my coding a million times and been researching for hours how to fix my problem.

The only thing i can think as to why it might not be working, is that the code they say to put into the "viewDidLoad" which i have been unable to do as "viewDidLoad" is in "ViewController.m" and i can't get the code "PFObject" in there.

I hope i have made sense because i really need help!!

I have been unable to post a print screen of what the instructions in parse say so i will quote them below:

"Copy and paste this code into your app, for example in the viewDidLoad method (or inside another method that gets called when you run your app):

```
PFObject *testobject = [PFObject objectWithClassName: @"test Object"];
testObject[@"foo"]=@"bar";
[testObject = saveInBackground]; "
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!!

Comment: Whoops i didnt mean to put in the equals sign in testobject saveinbackground, or the " at the very end. Without these it still doesnt work. Xcode isnt recognising "pfobject" in the view controller that is my problem

Comment: i just got the problem with "pfobejct" working, but its still saying "no data yet..." when i try to test it in parse. I cannot figure out what i have done wrong i have followed the instructions step by step!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get why there is "=" in below line of your code,

```
[testObject = saveInBackground]; "
```

But I have used parse and below is a simple example of it,

```
PFObject *userObj = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"YOUR_CLASS_NAME"];
userObj[@"name"] = @"walle";
userObj[@"job"] = @"stackOverFlow";
userObj[@"hobby"] = @"apple ;)";
[userObj save];
```

Hope this is what you looking for ! If anything else is there do let me know.

Comment: whoops didn't mean to put that = sign in when i typed it out!

Comment: but thank you for that! when you used that code what section of your project did you put it in? did you put it in appdelegate or viewcontroller?

Comment: This I put in a IBAction method as on tapping onto button(connected with this ibaction) I saved a object with all above details onto parse side. So where you will put it will depend on use case of ur app.

Comment: @oheffernan your welcome and vote up/ticking my answer would be appreciated.

Comment: @oheffernan sorry but u didn't tick my answer.

Comment: i tried to but it says i havnt got enough points yet! As soon as i get enough i will tick it. Sorry!